# How can I create a loop that creates functions with data from an array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, function, loops

How to do something like this in a loop?
Or is there a better way to do it?

```js
      $('#btndelete' + rowid[i]).click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php?id=rowid[i]",
        success: function(a) {
                $('#div-content').html(a);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Daan, End of the day, they are attached in loop only ;)

Comment: Use `class selector`/`any selector` which will return collection.

Comment: Can't you just save all rowid values in one variable(may b array) n pass on controller side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* put it in a loop, by giving the handlers something to close over that won't change, like an argument in a function call you make:

```
rowid.forEach(function(value) {
    $('#btndelete' + value).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete.php?id=" + value,
            success: function(a) {
                $('#div-content').html(a);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

(If `rowid` isn't an array, you can easily make it one with `Array.from` [ES2015, but shimmable] or `Array.prototype.slice.call(rowid)`.)

More details here: [*JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

**But**, in this particular case, you don't need to create a bunch of handler functions; put the `rowid[i]` on the element and then use a single handler for all of them:

```
rowid.forEach(function(value) {
    $("#btndelete" + value).data("rowid", value);
});
$("[id^=btndelete]").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php?id=" + $(this).data("rowid"),
        success: function(a) {
            $('#div-content').html(a);
        }
    });
});
```

Now a single handler handles all of them.

**Or** if these buttons are added/removed dynamically, you might use event delegation on some container.